# Como mostrar os dados vindo no banco em um gráfico Highcharts no ASP NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, highcharts

Boa tarde,

Estou tentando mostrar informações vindas do banco em um Gráfico Highchart, mais apesar de conseguir integrar ele ao projeto, não consigo passar os valores das informações vindas do banco para o gráfico.
Se alguém já trabalhou ou tem alguma ideia de como poderia fazer isso agradeceria a ajuda.

Segue código da controller que gerá os relatórios:

```
namespace DinheiroControlado.Controllers
{
public class RelatorioController : Controller
{

    private DinheiroControladoBD db2 = new DinheiroControladoBD();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var cookie = DinheiroControlado.Repositorios.RepositoriosUsuarios.VerificaSeOUsuarioEstaLogado();
        //retorna Categoria agrupado e valor destas categorias SUM() para mostrar no gráfico
        var dados = (from d in db2.Movimentacoes
                     join c in db2.Categorias on d.IDCategoria equals c.IDCategoria
                     where d.IDUsuario == cookie.IDUsuario
                     group d by c.Descricao into g
                     select new ItemGrafico { Categoria = g.Key, Valor = g.Sum(d => d.Valor) }).Take(5);



        DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart")
            .InitChart(new Chart { PlotShadow = false })
            .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Relatório Mensal" })
            .SetTooltip(new Tooltip { Formatter = "function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %'; }" })
            .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
            {
                Pie = new PlotOptionsPie
                {
                    AllowPointSelect = true,
                    Cursor = Cursors.Pointer,
                    DataLabels = new PlotOptionsPieDataLabels
                    {
                        Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000"),
                        ConnectorColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000"),
                        Formatter = "function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %'; }"
                    }
                }
            })
            .SetSeries(new Series
            {
                Type = ChartTypes.Pie,
                Name = "Browser share",
                Data = new Data(new object[]
                {
                    new object[] { "Firefox", 45.0 },
                    new object[] { "IE", 26.8 },
                    new object[] { "Chrome",12.8},
                    new object[] { "Safari", 8.5 },
                    new object[] { "Opera", 6.2 },
                    new object[] { "Others", 0.7 }
                })
            });

        return View(chart);
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, como não encontrei saída para este problema, resolvi criando um vetor para receber as informações do gráfico e depois fazendo varias verificações Ifs para saber a quantidade de informações que aparecerão no gráfico, segue o código caso alguém esteja com o mesmo problema e ainda não soube como resolver.

```
if (contador == 1)
        {
            DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart3 = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart3")
            .InitChart(new Chart { PlotShadow = false })
            .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Demonstrativo das Despesas - Periodo de " + ini + " a " + fim + "." })
            .SetTooltip(new Tooltip { Formatter = "function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %'; }" })
            .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
            {
                Pie = new PlotOptionsPie
                {
                    AllowPointSelect = true,
                    Cursor = Cursors.Pointer,
                    DataLabels = new PlotOptionsPieDataLabels
                    {
                        Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000"),
                        ConnectorColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000"),
                        Formatter = "function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %'; }"
                    }
                }
            })
            .SetSeries(new Series
            {
                Type = ChartTypes.Pie,
                Name = "Browser share",
                Data = new Data(new object[]
                {
                    new object[] { chartValuesC[0], chartValuesV[0]}
                })
            });

            return View(chart3);
        }
        else if (contador == 2)
        {
            DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart3 = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart3")
            .InitChart(new Chart { PlotShadow = false })
            .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Demonstrativo das Despesas - Periodo de " + ini + " a " + fim + "." })
            .SetTooltip(new Tooltip { Formatter = "function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %'; }" })
            .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
            {
                Pie = new PlotOptionsPie
                {
                    AllowPointSelect = true,
                    Cursor = Cursors.Pointer,
                    DataLabels = new PlotOptionsPieDataLabels
                    {
                        Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000"),
                        ConnectorColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000"),
                        Formatter = "function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %'; }"
                    }
                }
            })
            .SetSeries(new Series
            {
                Type = ChartTypes.Pie,
                Name = "Browser share",
                Data = new Data(new object[]
                {
                    new object[] { chartValuesC[0], chartValuesV[0]},
                    new object[] { chartValuesC[1], chartValuesV[1]}
                })
            });

            return View(chart3);
        }
        else if (contador == 3)
        {
            DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart3 = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart3")
            .InitChart(new Chart { PlotShadow = false })
            .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Demonstrativo das Despesas - Periodo de " + ini + " a " + fim + "." })
            .SetTooltip(new Tooltip { Formatter = "function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %'; }" })
            .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
            {
                Pie = new PlotOptionsPie
                {
                    AllowPointSelect = true,
                    Cursor = Cursors.Pointer,
                    DataLabels = new PlotOptionsPieDataLabels
                    {
                        Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000"),
                        ConnectorColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000"),
                        Formatter = "function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %'; }"
                    }
                }
            })
            .SetSeries(new Series
            {
                Type = ChartTypes.Pie,
                Name = "Browser share",
                Data = new Data(new object[]
                {
                    new object[] { chartValuesC[0], chartValuesV[0]},
                    new object[] { chartValuesC[1], chartValuesV[1]},
                    new object[] { chartValuesC[2], chartValuesV[2]}
                })
            });

            return View(chart3);
        }
        else if (contador == 4)
        {
            DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart3 = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart3")
            .InitChart(new Chart { PlotShadow = false })
            .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Demonstrativo das Despesas - Periodo de " + ini + " a " + fim + "." })
            .SetTooltip(new Tooltip { Formatter = "function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %'; }" })
            .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
            {
                Pie = new PlotOptionsPie
                {
                    AllowPointSelect = true,
                    Cursor = Cursors.Pointer,
                    DataLabels = new PlotOptionsPieDataLabels
                    {
                        Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000"),
                        ConnectorColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000"),
                        Formatter = "function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %'; }"
                    }
                }
            })
            .SetSeries(new Series
            {
                Type = ChartTypes.Pie,
                Name = "Browser share",
                Data = new Data(new object[]
                {
                    new object[] { chartValuesC[0], chartValuesV[0]},
                    new object[] { chartValuesC[1], chartValuesV[1]},
                    new object[] { chartValuesC[2], chartValuesV[2]},
                    new object[] { chartValuesC[3], chartValuesV[3]}
                })
            });

            return View(chart3);
        }
        else if (contador >= 5)
        {
            DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart3 = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart3")
            .InitChart(new Chart { PlotShadow = false })
            .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Demonstrativo das Despesas - Periodo de " + ini + " a " + fim + "." })
            .SetTooltip(new Tooltip { Formatter = "function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %'; }" })
            .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
            {
                Pie = new PlotOptionsPie
                {
                    AllowPointSelect = true,
                    Cursor = Cursors.Pointer,
                    DataLabels = new PlotOptionsPieDataLabels
                    {
                        Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000"),
                        ConnectorColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000"),
                        Formatter = "function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %'; }"
                    }
                }
            })
            .SetSeries(new Series
            {
                Type = ChartTypes.Pie,
                Name = "Browser share",
                Data = new Data(new object[]
                {
                    new object[] { chartValuesC[0], chartValuesV[0]},
                    new object[] { chartValuesC[1], chartValuesV[1]},
                    new object[] { chartValuesC[2], chartValuesV[2]},
                    new object[] { chartValuesC[3], chartValuesV[3]},
                    new object[] { chartValuesC[4], chartValuesV[4]}
                })
            });

            return View(chart3);
        }
         else 
        {

            TempData["1"] = "Demostrativo mensal de Despesas sem dados para o período selecionado!";
            return View();
        }
```